# mkdir() and fopen() in borland C

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is creating 10 directories with `mkdir()` command and a  counter to increase the value.

**EXAMPLE**

> K:\directory1\
>   K:\directory2\
>   ..
>   K:\directory10\

In each created directory, I have to create 10 files:

> K:\directory1\file1.m3u
>   K:\directory1\file2.m3u
>   ..
>   K:\directory1\file10.m3u

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <alloc.h>

FILE *string;
char dirname[100]; // Make the array large enough
int q=0;

int main(void)
{   
    for (q=0;q<31;q++)
    {
        sprintf(dirname,"K:\\%dMarch2008",q+1);
        mkdir(dirname);

    }
}
```

The creation of the dir is not a problem. However, I am not able to do the second part of work, where I create the files into the new directories.

Comment: try to open files in `w` mode so if not present file will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop put a `fopen()`, `fclose()` pair perhaps with a few `fprintf()` in between

```
for (q = 0; q < 31; q++) {
      char filename[100];
      FILE *newfile;
      sprintf(dirname, "K:\\%dMarch2008", q + 1);
      mkdir(dirname);
      sprintf(filename, "%s\\file1.m3u", dirname);
      newfile = fopen(filename, "w");
      if (newfile == NULL) /* error */;
      fprintf(newfile, "line 1\n");
      fclose(newfile);
}
```